# Trying to find text in a userform text box if the text is there then add 1 + the text

Tags: vba, textbox, find, counter, userform

> I am trying to find text in a userform text box if the text is found then add + 1 to the front e.g 1 & (label.caption) when clicked again would then change this to 2 &(label.caption) Below is some of the code I've been trying to work with but to no avail, then this would have to be reversed so that when i need to reduce the amount it takes 1 of the value at a time then if no value remove from the text box.

```
Private Sub La01_Click()


If Uf_Device_selection.Option_Add_device.Value = True Then


      
           Dim Textfind As Range
           Dim Dset As Integer
        
        
        For Each Textfind In Uf_Device_selection.Text_Device_list.Value
        
           Dim myDevice As Variant
           Dim myDevices As Variant
           myDevices = TriageToArray(Texfind.Value, ",")
           
           For Each myDevice In myDevices
               
               Select Case myDevice
               Case Is = (Sheets(3).Range("M15").Value & La01.Caption & " , ")
                       Dset = Dset + 1
               End Select
           Next
           
         Next Textfind
            
        
    Sheets(3).Range("M15").Value = Dset + 1
             
    Uf_Device_selection.Text_Device_list.Value = Sheets(3).Range("M15").Value & " " & La01.Caption & " , " & Uf_Device_selection.Text_Device_list.Value
Else
    Uf_Device_selection.Text_Device_list.Value = Replace(Text_Device_list.Value, La01.Caption & " , ", "", 1, 1)
End If


End Sub
```

> Below is some of the code in my project this work for finding text in the cells but as you can see im finding it hard to convert to the userform text box

```
   Option Explicit

Sub try_to_find_text()
Dim ALCell As Range
Dim car As Integer
Dim van As Integer
Dim truck As Integer
Dim digger As Integer


For Each ALCell In ActiveSheet.Range("E21:E1000")

    Dim myVehicle As Variant
    Dim myVehicles As Variant
    myVehicles = TriageToArray(ALCell.Value,",")
    For Each myVehicle In myVehicles
    
        Select Case myVehicle
        
            Case Is = "car"
            
                car = car + 1  
 
            Case Is = "van"

                van = van + 1
            
            Case Is = "truck"

                truck = truck + 1
            
            Case Is = "digger"

                HCAS = HCAS + 1
              
            Case Is = ""
                   
        End Select
        
    Next

Next ALCell

ActiveSheet.Range("B13").Value = car
ActiveSheet.Range("C13").Value = van
ActiveSheet.Range("D13").Value = truck
ActiveSheet.Range("E13").Value = digger
End Sub


Public Function TriageToArray(ByVal ipString As String, Optional ByVal ipSeparator As String = " ") As Variant

    Dim myArray As Variant
    myArray = Split(ipString, ipSeparator)
    
    Dim myIndex As Long
    For myIndex = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    
        myArray(myIndex) = LCase$(Trim$(myArray(myIndex)))
        
    Next

    TriageToArray = myArray
    
End Function
```

> Any help would be much appreciated
>
> just to add I've been trying a new way see below but i now need a way to change the number at the front as now it will find the word and put the 2 in front of the 'caption'  but when its goes to 3 it put 2 3 'caption'

```
Private Sub La02_Click()
If Uf_Device_selection.Option_Add_device.Value = True Then
 
  

    Dim n As Long
    Dim nt As Long
    Dim Dset As Integer
    
        n = InStr(Uf_Device_selection.Text_Device_list.Value, La02.Caption & " ,")
        nt = InStr(Uf_Device_selection.Text_Device_list.Value, Sheets(3).Range("C30").Value & " " & La02.Caption & " ,")
        Dset = Sheets(3).Range("C30").Value
        
            If n = 0 Then
                  
                  Text_Device_list = La02.Caption + " , " + Text_Device_list.Value
                  Dset = Dset + 1
                  Sheets(3).Range("C30").Value = Dset
            Else
            
                Dset = Dset + 1
                Sheets(3).Range("C30").Value = Dset
                
                    If nt = 0 Then
                    
                        Text_Device_list = Replace(Text_Device_list.Value, La02.Caption & " , ", Sheets(3).Range("C30").Value & " " & La02.Caption & " , ", 1, 1)
                        
                    Else
                         
                        Text_Device_list = Replace(Text_Device_list.Value, Sheets(3).Range("C30").Value - 1 & " " & La02.Caption & " , ", Sheets(3).Range("30").Value & " " & La02.Caption & " , ", 1, 1)
                        MsgBox "done now onto replace"
                       
                    End If
                
            End If
    
Else
    Text_Device_list = Replace(Text_Device_list.Value, La02.Caption & " , ", "", 1, 1)
End If

End Sub
```

> now just last line of code to replace the number and capton with new number and caption

Answer (score 0):

> finally  figured it out

```
Private Sub La02_Click()


    Dim n As Long
    Dim nt As Long
    Dim dset As Integer
    Dim dset_1 As Integer
    Dim destplus As Integer
    
    n = InStr(Uf_Device_selection.Text_Device_list.Value, La02.Caption & " ,")
    nt = InStr(Uf_Device_selection.Text_Device_list.Value, Sheets(3).Range("X20").Value & " " & "X" & " " & La02.Caption & " ,")
    dset = Sheets(3).Range("X20").Value
    dset_1 = Sheets(3).Range("X20").Value - 1
    dsetplus = Sheets(3).Range("X20").Value + 1
    DsetR = Sheets(3).Range("AH20").Value


If Uf_Device_selection.Option_Add_device.Value = True Then
 
  

            
            If n = 0 Then
                  
                  Text_Device_list = La02.Caption + " , " + Text_Device_list.Value
                  dset = dset + 1
                  Sheets(3).Range("X20").Value = dset
            Else
            
                
                
                    If nt = 0 Then
                        dset = dset + 1
                        Sheets(3).Range("X20").Value = dset
                        Text_Device_list = Replace(Text_Device_list.Value, La02.Caption & " , ", dset & " " & "X" & " " & La02.Caption & " , ", 1, 1)
                        
                        
                    Else
                        
                        Text_Device_list = Replace(Text_Device_list.Value, dset & " " & "X" & " " & La02.Caption & " , ", dsetplus & " " & "X" & " " & La02.Caption & " , ", 1, 1)
                        dset = dset + 1
                        Sheets(3).Range("X20").Value = dset
                      
                    End If
                
            End If
    
Else

   
            
            If nt > 0 Then
                    If dset > 2 Then
                      
                        Text_Device_list = Replace(Text_Device_list.Value, dset & " " & "X" & " " & La02.Caption & " , ", dset_1 & " " & "X" & " " & La02.Caption & " , ", 1, 1)
                        dset = dset - 1
                        Sheets(3).Range("X20").Value = dset
                        
                    
                    Else
                
                       
                        Text_Device_list = Replace(Text_Device_list.Value, dset & " " & "X" & " " & La02.Caption & " , ", La02.Caption & " , ", 1, 1)
                        dset = dset - 2
                        Sheets(3).Range("X20").Value = dset
                    End If
            Else
            
                dset = dset - 1
                Text_Device_list = Replace(Text_Device_list.Value, La02.Caption & " , ", "", 1, 1)
                
            End If
               
End If

End Sub
```

> so this code will add the caption from the label click to the userform text-box, also if you click again it will put "number of clicked times" , X ,"caption. it doesn't matter where in the text it is. also when the remove it clicked it will count down the "number of clicked" , X , caption. then remove from text box.